# Perf: how to display cache miss percentage from raw counters

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, perf, performancecounter, performance-measuring

I am using the `perf` tool on Linux with an Intel Xeon E5-1650 v4 processor (Broadwell architecture).

For several cache load/miss indicators, `perf stat` indicates that these are `<not supported>`:

```
$ perf stat -e L1-icache-loads,L1-icache-load-misses,L1-dcache-loads,L1-dcache-load-misses,LLC-loads,LLC-load-misses myprogram

 Performance counter stats for 'myprogram':

   <not supported>      L1-icache-loads                                             
           550.670      L1-icache-load-misses                                       
       103.926.211      L1-dcache-loads                                             
        17.266.056      L1-dcache-load-misses     #   16,61% of all L1-dcache accesses
   <not supported>      LLC-loads                                                   
   <not supported>      LLC-load-misses                                             

       0,159281699 seconds time elapsed

       0,138935000 seconds user
       0,020431000 seconds sys
```

From [this site](https://github.com/intel/perfmon/blob/main/BDW/events/broadwell_core.json) I managed to find the event code and umasks and I can specify the raw counters as follows:

```
$ perf stat -e cpu/event=0x80,umask=0x01,name=L1-icache-loads/,L1-icache-load-misses,L1-dcache-loads,L1-dcache-load-misses,cpu/event=0x2e,umask=0x4f,name=LLC-loads/,cpu/event=0x2e,umask=0x41,name=LLC-load-misses/ myprogram

 Performance counter stats for 'myprogram':

        30.724.476      L1-icache-loads                                               (65,33%)
           709.859      L1-icache-load-misses     <------------- NO PERCENTAGE -----> (65,37%)
       105.432.323      L1-dcache-loads                                               (65,95%)
        17.942.752      L1-dcache-load-misses     #   17,02% of all L1-dcache accesses  (68,38%)
        21.991.089      LLC-loads                                                     (68,71%)
            88.833      LLC-load-misses           <------------- NO PERCENTAGE -----> (66,25%)

       0,162608291 seconds time elapsed

       0,158630000 seconds user
       0,004139000 seconds sys
```

However, the `L1-icache-load-misses` it not given as a percentage of the `L1-icache-loads`, and similarly `LLC-load-misses` is not given as a percentage of the `LLC-loads`

**Question 1**: is there a way to tell `perft` to annotate a row with a percentage in terms of another row?

**Question 2**: is is possible to recompile my kernel or configure `perf` in order to map the event codes and umasks for my specific processor, so that `perf` will support the L1 and LLC cache counters and give percentages for the misses?

Comment: `ocperf.py` is Andy Kleen's wrapper for `perf` which had human-friendly names for events before mainline `perf` got them for my Skylake. (It downloads a data file from Intel to get event names.)  Worth trying it, although IDK if it would do percentages. https://github.com/andikleen/pmu-tools

Comment: If you are willing to rebuild perf, you could add any metrics (statistics computed arithmetically from counters) you wish. I'm not that familiar with Intel processors, but I know a bit about "powerpc". Here's an example set of metrics for "powerpc": https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/tools/perf/pmu-events/arch/powerpc/power9/metrics.json?h=v6.7.1